# How can I withdraw my WETH from my contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I deployed this contract.

https://github.com/flashbots/simple-arbitrage/blob/master/contracts/BundleExecutor.sol

And I transferred WETH to this contract.

How can I withdraw the WETH from this contract?

In the first place, was it not necessary to send WETH to this contract?

Comment: i have same problem to retire from my contract to my wallet.
my contract do not have call funcion.
can you help my to compiler call funcion to tranfer my found to my acount. sorry for my bad english. thank you for your helpme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep WETH in the contract I believe to make the swaps.

To withdraw, you can call the `call(_to, _value, _data)` function with:

- `_to = WETH_ADDRESS`
- `_value = 0`
- `_data`:

```
_data = ethers.utils.hexConcat([
    '0xa9059cbb',  // selector of transfer(address,uint256)
    ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        ['address', 'uint256'],
        [MY_ADDRESS, WETH_AMOUNT_IN_WEI]
    )
])
```

with `MY_ADDRESS` your wallet address, and `WETH_AMOUNT_IN_WEI` the amount in the contract you want to withdraw.

Basically with this method your contract will call WETH to make a transfer to your wallet.

Comment: Thanks very much! I successfully withdrew it!